# Retrieve the Active Directory groups of the current user

Tags: c#, .net, security, active-directory

How can I get the Active Directory groups the current user belongs to?

Is there a way to do this using the `DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` library?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I found how. It turned out to be very simple with `DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` :

```
using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;

PrincipalSearchResult<Principal> groups = UserPrincipal.Current.GetGroups();

IEnumerable<string> groupNames = groups.Select(x => x.SamAccountName);
```

Comment: It only returns security groups ?

Comment: The GetGroups method returns Active Directory groups objects.